# Verify the Reflexivity, Symmetry and Transitivity of the relation $R=\{(a,b):a\leq b^2\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality, relations, equivalence-relations

> Show that the relation $R$ in the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers, defined as $R=\{(a,b):a\leq b^2\}$ is neither reflexive nor symmetric nor transitive.

We can verify this by bringing examples, but is it possible to solve it directly from the expression of the given relation ?

$$
a\le a^2\implies a^2-a\geq 0\implies a^2-2.\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\ge0\\
\implies\Big(a-\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2\geq \Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2\implies\bigg|a-\frac{1}{2}\bigg|\geq\frac{1}{2}\\
a-\frac{1}{2}\geq\frac{1}{2}\text{ if }a\geq\frac{1}{2}\;\text{ (or) }\;a-\frac{1}{2}\leq-\frac{1}{2}\text{ if }a<\frac{1}{2}\\
a\geq 1\;\&\;a\geq\frac{1}{2}\;\text{ or }\;a\leq0\;\&\;a<\frac{1}{2}\\
a\geq 1 \text{ or } a\leq0
$$
So for all $a\in(0,1)$, $a\nleq a^2\implies(a,a)\notin R$, thus not reflexive.

Similarly, how do I prove that the given relation is not symmetric and not transitive without any examples ?

Or atleast how do I find example or counterexample without guessing ?

Comment: In your first sentence, substitute "always" with "never" and you'll obtain a true statement (except in the case where there are finitey many objects and you know them all).

Comment: You want to show an existential  statement of the form $\color{red}\exists x\colon (x,x,)\notin R$ without constructively exhibiting such $x$? -- In your proof of "not reflexive", how do you know that $(0,1)\ne \emptyset$?

Comment: I think the OP means without using a particular counterexample

Comment: Your proof for lack of symmetry is incorrect; consider for example the case where $b\lt 0$

Comment: Your factorisation in the first case can be considerably shortened - $a^2-a\ge 0\Rightarrow a(a-1)\ge 0\Rightarrow a\in\mathbb{R}-(0,1)$

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe thats right. but, how do I prove it for other two cases ?, because i dont think bring examples and counter examples always easy, atleast for transitive case in the given example.

Comment: For the second part, something along the lines of $1\le a\le b$?

Comment: Similarly for the third part.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yup. bcz for transitive case, by just looking at the relation I don't see any counter examples to prove its not transitive. So, how do I prove it then ?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe could u pls elaborate on that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you come up with a counterexample to transitivity?

If you are having trouble, one thing to try is to see *why* you cannot **prove** transitivity. The roadblock to the proof may point you in the direction of a counterexample.

Suppose $a,b,c$ are real numbers, $a\leq b^2$, and $b\leq c^2$. When can you prove $a\leq c^2$, or what prevents you from proving it?

If $a\leq 0$, there’s not going to be a problem. So let’s assume $a\gt 0$.

If $b\leq 0$, then $b\leq c^2$ certainly holds. Here is where we run into problems, because $c^2$ can be pretty small and still be larger than $b$, even if $b^2$ is larger than $a$. So... what if we pick a $b\lt 0$ but with large enough square, and then pick a $c$ with very small square, smaller than $a$? Will that work?